# How can I read text in a file path in Java Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using Java Spring Boot to build a simple desktop app and there, in the following constructor for the class `EmailSenderHandler` I want to set `this.emailBody` property to the text content in the HTML file stored in `htmlFilePath`. I can't think of a proper method to do that, can anyone help me with that? Thanks in advance.

```
public EmailSenderHandler(String inputFilePath, 
                          String csvFilePath, 
                          String htmlFilePath, 
                          String fromEmail, 
                          String password, 
                          String fromEmailName, 
                          String emailBody, 
                          AtomicLong progressCount, 
                          DataProcessor dataProcessor)
{

        this.inputFilePath = inputFilePath;
        this.csvFilePath = csvFilePath;
        this.htmlFilePath = htmlFilePath;
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.password = password;
        this.fromEmailName = fromEmailName;
        this.emailBody = emailBody;
        this.progressCount = progressCount;
        this.dataProcessor = dataProcessor;
    }
```

Comment: If it's on the same machine the program is running on you should read it the same way you read a file in any other java application. Or are you asking how it's done in java in general?

Comment: Yes I am asking how it is done in Java. And also yes it is stored locally in the machine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can read the body later,

```java
public EmailSenderHandler(String inputFilePath, 
                          String csvFilePath, 
                          String htmlFilePath, 
                          String fromEmail, 
                          String password, 
                          String fromEmailName, 
                          AtomicLong progressCount, 
                          DataProcessor dataProcessor)
{
        this.inputFilePath = inputFilePath;
        this.csvFilePath = csvFilePath;
        this.htmlFilePath = htmlFilePath;
        this.fromEmail = fromEmail;
        this.password = password;
        this.fromEmailName = fromEmailName;
        this.progressCount = progressCount;
        this.dataProcessor = dataProcessor;

        this.emailBody = readEmailBodyFromHtml(htmlFilePath);
    }
```

and implement the `readEmailBodyFromHtml` method

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to utilize a character input stream to read the html file and add to the mail body string.So first of all you create `new File(htmlFilePath)` then you apply a new instance of character stream with the file in the constructor.

Comment: Can you link me to a thread on utilizing a character input stream to read the HTML file?

Comment: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstreamreader.html hope this helps